# Asp.Net Mvc Layout page causes multiple redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I add layout on all pages in my Asp.net mvc project, all methods are called three times. But this problem is solved when I set the layout page setting to null. I am not quite sure if this problem stems from the layout page, but I absolutely have to solve it. Because the log and all other structures are working three times, and I have a lot of problems with tempdata.

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />
    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-sweetalert/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/css/components-md.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_components" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/css/plugins-md.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT STYLES -->
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/layouts/layout3/css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/layouts/layout3/css/themes/default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/layouts/layout3/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/assets/pages/css/error.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- END THEME LAYOUT STYLES -->

</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->
<body class="page-container-bg-solid page-md">
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="page-wrapper-row">
            <div class="page-wrapper-top">
                <!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
                <div class="page-header">
                    <!-- BEGIN HEADER TOP -->
                    <div class="page-header-top">
                        <div class="container">
                            <!-- BEGIN LOGO -->
                            <div class="page-logo">
                                <a>
                                    <img src="~/Content/Theme/arcelik-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo-default">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- END LOGO -->
                            <!-- BEGIN RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
                            @*<a href="javascript:;" class="menu-toggler"></a>*@
                            <!-- END RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
                            <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
                            <div class="top-menu" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" style="line-height:50px;">
                                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-user dropdown-dark">
                                        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
                                            <span class="username username-hide-mobile">@Html.Action("GetLoggedUserName", "Account")</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-separator">
                                        <span class="separator"></span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "login-form", id = "logoffForm" }))
                                        {
                                            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoffForm').submit();" class="btn btn-xs red">@Resources.Global.Logout<i class="icon-logout"></i></a>
                                        }
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="page-header-menu visible-desktop visible-tablet visible-phone">
                        <div class="container"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END HEADER -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-wrapper-row full-height">
            <div class="page-wrapper-middle">
                <!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
                <div class="page-container">
                    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
                    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
                        <div class="page-content">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="page-content-inner">
                                    @RenderBody()
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END PAGE CONTENT BODY -->
                        <!-- END CONTENT BODY -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- END CONTENT -->
                </div>
                <!-- END CONTAINER -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="../assets/global/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/global/plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/global/plugins/ie8.fix.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- BEGIN CORE PLUGINS -->
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/js.cookie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/jstree/dist/jstree.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-sweetalert/sweetalert.js"></script>
    <!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/global/scripts/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/pages/scripts/components-bootstrap-select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/layouts/layout3/scripts/layout.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/layouts/layout3/scripts/demo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-sidebar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-nav.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END THEME LAYOUT SCRIPTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //$('.bs-select').selectpicker({});
    </script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

To give an example, the users come to my page via the Crm system with the following action.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ToFolder(CrmIntegrationModel crmIntegrationModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return ErrorView(new Exception(ModelState.ToErrorString()));
        if (crmIntegrationModel.EntityGuid == Guid.Empty) return ErrorView(new ArgumentNullException(nameof(crmIntegrationModel.EntityGuid)));
        if (crmIntegrationModel.UserId == Guid.Empty) return ErrorView(new ArgumentNullException(nameof(crmIntegrationModel.UserId)));
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(crmIntegrationModel.EntityName)) return ErrorView(new ArgumentNullException(nameof(crmIntegrationModel.EntityName)));

        var applicationPath = Request.ApplicationPath == "/" ? "/" : Request.ApplicationPath + "/";
        TempData["CrmIntegrationModel"] = crmIntegrationModel;
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new RouteValueDictionary(new { userId = crmIntegrationModel.UserId, userType = crmIntegrationModel.UserType }));
    }
```

If the incoming model is correct, I'm redirecting the following action to login.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(Guid userId,UserType userType)
    {
        IAccount account = null;

        if (userType == UserType.SystemUser)
           account = _accountService.CheckSystemUser(userId);
        if (userType == UserType.Employee)
            account = _accountService.CheckEmployee(userId);

        if (account == null) throw new Exception(ErrorMessages.UserNotFound);

        var roles = account.Roles.ToArray();

        var principalModel = new CustomPrincipalViewModel
        {
            UserId = account.UserId.ToString(),
            FullName = account.FullName,
            Roles = roles,
            Language = account.Language
        };

        var userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(principalModel);
        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, principalModel.FullName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, userData);
        var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        SetCulture(account.Language.CultureCode);

        return RedirectToAction("RedirectToFolder","Upload");
    }
```

After the login process, the following action is repeated three times.

```
    public ActionResult RedirectToFolder()
    {
        var crmIntegrationModel = TempData["CrmIntegrationModel"] as CrmIntegrationModel;
        if (crmIntegrationModel == null) return ErrorView(new ArgumentNullException($"crmIntegrationModel"));

        _entityId = crmIntegrationModel.EntityGuid;
        _systemUser = crmIntegrationModel.UserId.ToString();
        _portalEntity = _verifyService.VerifyEntity(crmIntegrationModel.EntityName, crmIntegrationModel.EntityGuid);
        _folderPath = _portalEntity.FolderPath;

        try
        {
            var folder = _sharePointFolderService.GetFolderByTitle(_portalEntity.FolderPath);
            Session["OpenedFolderId"] = folder.ParentFolderId;
            Session["SelectedFolderId"] = folder.Id;
            Session["DocumentTypeId"] = _portalEntity.DocumentTypeId != Guid.Empty && _portalEntity.EntityType == EntityType.Case ? (object)_portalEntity.DocumentTypeId : "-1";
            Session["Entity"] = _portalEntity;

            return _portalEntity.EntityType == EntityType.Policy ? RedirectToAction("Index", "Policy") : RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ErrorView(ex);
        }
    }
```

EDIT : 
I cannot solve this problem. Removed everything in _layout page one by one but nothing is changed. Could anyone help with remote connection, please ?

Comment: Which methods are called 3 times?

Comment: I added some code details to my question @Shyju